# Windows Security Accounts on different languages - Users, Everyone.. - Icacls

Tags: windows, icacls

I want to grant full access rights for all users for a specific folder. I already found out how to do it with Icacls:

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foldername" /grant:r Users:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

or

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foldername" /grant:r Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

My question: For this to actually works I have to use the words 'Usários' and 'Todos' instead of Users and Everyone because I am using a Portuguese version of Windows.

So how is the best way for me to code it on my applications? Do I have to keep a track of how this accounts are called on different languages by Windows, figure out how to get the Language of the installed version and so on, or there is a direct and better way to find how this accounts are called?

Comment: use *sid* instead friendly name, say `/grant:r *S-1-1-0:(OI)(CI)F /T`

Comment: You can also use [SDDL abbreviations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sid-strings) prefixed by "*" instead of the SID, e.g. `*WD` instead of `*S-1-1-0` and `*BU` instead of `*S-1-5-32-545`.